# I'm new to making a discord welcome bot with python and I have a problem

Tags: python

```
#discordbot.py

import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready.')

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(f'{member} has joined a server.')

@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    print(f'{member} has left a server.')
```

I ran python with this script. But there aren't some changes on on_member_join(member): ~ and on_member_remove(member): ~. Why don't know why and I'm new with python. I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Print will only print out the string in the console. I assume you want the message to appear in a designated channel so you can do something like this:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready.')

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = client.get_channel('insert the channel id of your choice')
    await channel.send(f'{member} has joined a server.')

@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    channel = client.get_channel('insert the channel id of your choice')
    await channel.send(f'{member} has left a server.')
```

Answer (score 0):

I see your code and I can tell you that I had the same problem.
You just need to enable "Server Members Intent" into your developer page (https://discord.com/developers/applications/YOUR_BOT_ID/bot).
Then go into you bot and add some new lines:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
```

and then, into the client var definition:

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.', intents=intents)
```

and you're ready to go! I hope I helped you!